# Trying to pass value from local storage as an argument to another function on initialization (Angular 11)

Tags: angular, typescript, subscribe

I am getting a value from local storage (I have put it in a console.log, and it comes back as intended):

```
getBranchId(): Observable<any>
  {
    const branchId = localStorage['branch'];
    return of (branchId);
  }
```

I want to set the value returned from the above function as the parameter of another function on initialization of the component. I have done the following:

```
populateTable() {
    const id = this.branchService.getBranchId();
    id.subscribe(resp => {
      this.branchService.getBranchStock(resp).subscribe(
        (resp: any) => {
          // Do something with resp
        },
        (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      )
    })
  }
```

I then run the "populateTable()" function within the ngOnInit as follows:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.populateTable()
  }
```

The above returns a POST 415 error, and the http error response of the second subscribe is hit. However, when sending any other value, for eg. "45" as follows:

```
this.subs.add(this.branchService.getBranchStock(45).subscribe(...)
```

Everything works just fine. I assume the issue is that everything is running together at the same time, and that the resp is not acquired quickly enough to be sent to the second function. Are there any workarounds to this issue?

Comment: Are you sure, that you're getting a value from the `localStorage`?

Comment: @Batajus yep. When subscribing to the id on initialization, I got the value I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the API doesn't like the string you are sending. The `localStorage` stores things in string (JSON) format. So you need to convert this first when obtaining it:

```
getBranchId(): Observable<any> {
  const branchId = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('branch'));

  return of(branchId);
}
```

[image]